# How do you set up a vpn for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, proxy, openvpn

As the title says I am wondering how to successfully set up a free vpn in Ubuntu? I apologize if this answer has already been given if so I cannot find it, or at least I cannot execute it successfully if I have found the answer. I appreciate the help!
I would like to know for OpenVPN and also for ProtonVPN please. I cannot seem to find a working solution from searching. I am newer to Ubuntu but am just OK with the terminal, I can for the most part understand and execute the commands. I am also wondering is there a difference to 18.04 LTS and 18.04.2 LTS? Everything I can find for the setup seems to refer to just 18.04 I have tried these with no success:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Bump, still looking for help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found it but am still having a little trouble
https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/